# images in html java mail are displayed both inline and as attachment in Yahoomail

Tags: java, email, velocity

[having same problem that raise in below link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226499/images-in-html-java-mail-are-displayed-both-inline-and-as-attachment-in-yahoo)

code i use is

```
public class MailSender {
private static final MedikmLogger logger = MedikmLogger
        .getLogger(MailSender.class);
private String SMTP_HOST_NAME, SMTP_AUTH_USER, SMTP_AUTH_PWD;
 private static String MedikmDicomPath=AppConfig.getAppConfig().getProperty("images");
public void postMail(String recipients[], String subject, String message,
        String from) throws MessagingException {
    try{
        Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    ApplicationSource applicationSource = ApplicationSource.getAppConfig();
    SMTP_HOST_NAME = applicationSource.getProperty("SMTP_SERVER");
    SMTP_AUTH_USER = applicationSource.getProperty("MAIL_SENDER");
    SMTP_AUTH_PWD = applicationSource.getProperty("MAIL_SENDER_PASSWORD");
    /*
     * logger.log(Level.SEVERE," ############### SMTP_AUTH_PWD ############### "
     * +SMTP_AUTH_PWD); logger.log(Level.SEVERE,
     * " ############### SMTP_HOST_NAME ############### "+SMTP_HOST_NAME);
     * logger
     * .log(Level.SEVERE," ############### SMTP_AUTH_USER ############### "
     * +SMTP_AUTH_USER);
     */
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
    msg.setFrom(addressFrom);

    InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[recipients.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);
    }
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
    // Setting the Subject and Content Type
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    System.out.println("++++++++++++++++MedikmDicomPath++++++++++++++++++"+MedikmDicomPath);

    MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");


    VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
    ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath"); 
    ve.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
   ve.init();
   /*  next, get the Template  */
   Template t = ve.getTemplate("templates/emailtemplate.vm");
   System.out.println("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=TTTT-=-=-=-=-=-=-"+t);
   /*  create a context and add data */
   VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
   context.put("message", message);
   /* now render the template into a StringWriter */
   StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
   t.merge( context, writer );
   /* show the World */
   System.out.println("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=WRITER-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-"+ writer.toString() );    


    String messageText = messageText(t, context);
    BodyPart part= new  MimeBodyPart();
    part.setContent(messageText, "text/html");
    // add it
    multipart.addBodyPart(part);
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    String f= this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getFile();
    String pathArr[] = f.split("/WEB-INF/classes/");
    FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource(pathArr[0]+"/images/homelogo.png");
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
    messageBodyPart.addHeader("Content-ID","<senny>");
    // add it
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);




    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
   // String f1= this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getFile();
   FileDataSource fds1 = new FileDataSource(pathArr[0]+"/images/rpci-logo.png");
    messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds1));
    messageBodyPart2.addHeader("Content-ID","<image>");
    // add it
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);
    msg.setContent(multipart);
    //msg.setContent(messageText, "text/html");
    System.out.println("Sending Message");
    Transport.send(msg);
    System.out.println("Message Sent");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        String username = SMTP_AUTH_USER;
        String password = SMTP_AUTH_PWD;
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }
}
private String messageText(Template template, VelocityContext velocityContext){
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    template.merge(velocityContext, stringWriter);
    return stringWriter.toString();
}
```

}
above code works fine in gmail but when same code use in seding mail to yahoo it display images and that images added in attachment as well please help..

Comment: If it is the same problem, why are you asking the same question again? This is known as a [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: but solution of this problem is still not available sir....

Comment: And why do you hope that this one will get one then?

Comment: In that case, please try to improve the original question through [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) and by following the advice in the help center about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: sorry to say sir but i just want to divert developers mind on this problem not even a single comment come on this problem previously ...

Comment: question is clear i don't think what is unclear in that question....

Answer (score 0):

```
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
    messageBodyPart.addHeader("Content-ID", "<senny>");
    messageBodyPart.addHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
```

by adding above line problem is getting solve thank you every one for your time...